# Using socket.io with express.js controller

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io with controller functions in express.js, but the socket.on is  not calling into the io.on() in server.js

```
// at server.js
const postRoute = require('./routes/postReqRouter')

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log('=====SOCKET Connected======', socket.id)

   socket.on('taskDataSOCK', function (data) {
      console.log('====TaskData Found====', data)
      io.emit('taskDataSOCK', { data })
   })
}

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.io = io
   next()
})

app.use('/api/post', postRoute)

// postReqRouter.js
router.route('/get-all-data').post(contoller.getData)

module.exports = router

// at controller.js
exports.getData = (req, res) => {
    /// `enter code here`
    res.io.emit(‘'taskDataSOCK', { data })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `io.on('connection')` is called when a client is connected you can connect to the same socket server using [client](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) (frontend) or from another nodejs app see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)